# Absolute Turning Motor in NXC

Tags: nxt, programming, motor, nxc

How can I turn my motor **to** 123 degrees, not **for** 123 degrees?

I tried the `PosRegSetAngle("output", "angle")` command and didn't work.

[Documentation for PosRegSetAngle](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/nxcdoc/nxcapi/group___output_module_functions_gadbb21feba9bd8d38e9ac7accedc4855a.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PosRegSetAngle should set the position of the motor relative to the position the motor was in when regulation was enabled. In what way didn't it work when you tried this?

It sounds like you may be asking how to wait for the rotation to finish. I'm not sure if there is a built-in way to do this in NXC or not, but I think that something along these lines should get you there:

```
# Enable regulation
PosRegEnable(OUT_A);

# Set target angle
PosRegSetAngle(OUT_A, 123);

# Busy loop while the motor turns
while (GetOutput(OUT_A, ActualSpeedField) != 0) {}
```